# getting Null Pointer Exception in View.getDrawingCache()

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I am trying to get View converted in bitmap.
In emulator my program is working fine and running as expected but when I run the same code in Device it gives null pointer Exception at particular line :

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
```

where view is object of RelativeLayout having Layout of current Activity.
Can someone guide how can I resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code so we can see what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Can u plz share ur code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `measure` and `layout` on your view before using `getDrawingCache()`. Otherwise it will return null.

Comment: You can still get null even with measure and layout set. This problem remains unsolved.